# Executing a Super-user command through .bashrc

Tags: bash, sudo, lamp, bashrc

Is it possible to execute a super-user command in .bashrc? And if so, how?

It would save me having to execute "sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start" on each startup. I've considered using the LAMP stack from the repositories, but it doesn't really meet my needs (I need to be able to move the entire LAMP stack folder).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also see [Starting and stopping server with a desktop shortcut](http://askubuntu.com/q/98047/236).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a bad idea, because `~/.bashrc` is executed for each terminal you open.

You should consider to put the command in `/etc/rc.local`, or to create a custom startup script in `/etc/init.d` (and the corresponding symbolic links in `/etc/rc*.d`).