# Starting and stopping server with a desktop shortcut

Tags: command-line, lamp

I use

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

and

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
```

every time in order to start and stop the lampp server installed in my computer.

Is there some way by which I can create an icon on my desktop, so that the above command get executed in terminal simply by clicking on the icon?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Without being clever, you can create two launchers for your desktop to start and stop. If you want to sink more time into this you could write a script for a single launcher to  toggle on/off, but I'll leave that up to you.

1. Load a terminal and run `gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new $HOME/Desktop`. If you're using something older than 11.10, you might be able to right click the desktop and just click New Launcher.
2. Give it a name like "Turn LAMP server Off", select a nice icon, don't worry about the comment.
3. For the command, you want something like this:

   ```
   gksu /opt/lampp/lampp stop
   ```
4. Click OK, test it out and then rinse and repeat for the start version.

Answer (score -1):

you can make the sh file of this command. **be careful you navigate to the proper directory before writing command in the sh file.**

then you can execute sh file.

to execute sh file follow following

```
Right-click on the file.
Go to Properties. And then the 'Permissions' tab.
Check 'Allow executing file as program'. Say OK.
Now double-click on the file the way you open any other file.
That should run the script in .sh file.
```

also refer http://www.zimbio.com/Ubuntu+Linux/articles/294/How+install+run+sh+file+Linux

Comment: can i know why down vote?